# Google Plus sign in 'Choose an Account' dialog appears twice

Tags: android, google-plus

I'm implementing Google+ sign in via the developer documentation. My `onConnectionFailed` methods is being called after I choose an account to sign in with the error `RESOLUTION_REQUIRED` (error code 6). This launches another 'Choose an Account' dialog which then works (takes me to permissions) if I select the same account. I'm not sure why it prompts another dialog. I start with `resolveSignInError` Any insight?

Also, selecting an account from 'Choose an account' shows permissions, if I hit cancel at that point and select another account from the dial, it shows the wrong picture for the permissions or sometimes no picture at all. I've also gotten `An internal error has occurred` toast once.

```
@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    if (!mIntentInProgress) {
        // Store the ConnectionResult so that we can use it later when the user clicks
        // 'sign-in'.
        mConnectionResult = connectionResult;
        if (mSignInClicked) {
            // The user has already clicked 'sign-in' so we attempt to resolve all
            // errors until the user is signed in, or they cancel.
            resolveSignInError();
        }
    }
}

private void resolveSignInError() {
    if (mConnectionResult != null && mConnectionResult.hasResolution()) {
        try {
            mIntentInProgress = true;
            startIntentSenderForResult(mConnectionResult.getResolution().getIntentSender(),
                    RC_SIGN_IN, null, 0, 0, 0);

        } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
            // The intent was canceled before it was sent.  Return to the default
            // state and attempt to connect to get an updated ConnectionResult.
            mIntentInProgress = false;
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) {
            mSignInClicked = false;
        }
        mIntentInProgress = false;
        if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting()) {
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code is working fine for me, Please update yours with it and check.

```
private void resolveSignInError() {
        if (mConnectionResult.hasResolution()) {
            try {
                mIntentInProgress = true;
                mConnectionResult.startResolutionForResult(this, RC_SIGN_IN);
            } catch (SendIntentException e) {
                mIntentInProgress = false;
                mGoogleApiClient.connect();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
        if (!result.hasResolution()) {
            GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(result.getErrorCode(), this, 0).show();
            return;
        }

        if (!mIntentInProgress) {

            mConnectionResult = result;

            if (mSignInClicked) {

                resolveSignInError();
            }
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int responseCode, Intent intent) {
        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            if (responseCode != RESULT_OK) {
                mSignInClicked = false;
            }

            mIntentInProgress = false;

            if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting()) {
                mGoogleApiClient.connect();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

In "onActivityForResult", you should remove the first line "super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);"

Also, just to be sure, you create your GoogleApiClient in onCreate, connect it in onStart() and disconnect it in onStop()?

Do you call resolveSignInError() from anywhere else in your code?

Comment: Thanks. I had a super.onActivityForResult() and removing it (resp. only calling it when I didn't handle the result myself) solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Enter signout Function in getprofileinformation(). Like that.Hope ,this code can help you

```
 private void getProfileInformation() {
        try {
            if (Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient) != null) {
                Person currentPerson = Plus.PeopleApi
                        .getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient);
                String personName = currentPerson.getDisplayName();
                String personPhotoUrl = currentPerson.getImage().getUrl();
                String personGooglePlusProfile = currentPerson.getUrl();
                String email = Plus.AccountApi.getAccountName(mGoogleApiClient);

                forget_login_txt.setText(personName+"   "+email);
                Log.e(TAG, "Name: " + personName + ", plusProfile: "
                        + personGooglePlusProfile + ", email: " + email
                        + ", Image: " + personPhotoUrl);


                personPhotoUrl = personPhotoUrl.substring(0,
                        personPhotoUrl.length() - 2)
                        + PROFILE_PIC_SIZE;


                signOutFromGplus();



            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Person information is null", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```